# I'd like to make figure with gridspec(), which I hope there are not blank between subplots. The result is different from what I expected

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my function:

```
def plot(samples):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4, wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
    #gs.update(wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

    for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i])
        plt.axis('off')
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        #ax.set_aspect('equal')
        plt.imshow(sample.reshape(28, 28), cmap='Greys_r')

    return fig
```

where `sample` is numpy.ndarrray(,784)

The result is:

[image]

Since the figure as well as the images are square, I would not expect any white lines appearing in between the subplots. Is there any way to get rid of them?

Comment: How is this different - what did you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

The default subplot params are

```
left : 0.125 # The left side of the subplots of the figure
right : 0.9  # The right side of the subplots of the figure
bottom : 0.1 # The bottom of the subplots of the figure
top : 0.9    # The top of the subplots of the figure
```

Due to `right-left < top-bottom`, a square figure with square images will still leave some asymmectric space between the images.

In order to obtain equal margins, make e.g. `left=0.1` as well:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4, top=0.9, bottom=0.1, left=0.1, right=0.9,
                             wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np

def plot(samples):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4, top=0.9, bottom=0.1, left=0.1, right=0.9,
                           wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

    for i, sample in enumerate(samples):
        ax = plt.subplot(gs[i])
        plt.axis('off')
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        #ax.set_aspect('equal')
        plt.imshow(sample.reshape(28, 28), cmap='Greys_r')

    return fig

samples = [np.random.rand(28*28) for i in range(4*4)]
plot(samples)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This now looks indeed like a single image and has no spacings between subplots.